# Hide is not working Iphone and Mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we call the HideModal() method the popupContainer div will be hiding.
it is working fine in all the browsers but not working on Iphone and mobile devices .

```
function HideModal() {
    $("#popupContainer").modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code or, what would be the best choice, a jsFiddle or plunker.

Comment: We use bootstrap model

Answer (score 0):

could you create a jsfiddle so we can see where's the problem.
anyway i've created a pen , and i tested it on my phone , it works fin for me
codepen : http://codepen.io/hmache/pen/bZaNmW

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  });
});
```